# Scheduler using Quartz is not calling immediately

Tags: quartz-scheduler

I configured a scheduler using `quartz-2.2.1.jar` to repeat every 10 minutes. It is working fine and is getting triggered on every 10 minutes but the first trigger is not taking place immediately. The first trigger is taking place only after 10 minutes.

Can someone help me out in this?

Code Snippet:

```
JobDetail jobDetail = JobBuilder.newJob()
.withIdentity("key_expiration_email_notifier")
.ofType(KeyExpirationEmailNotifier.class).build();

Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
.withIdentity("key_expiration_email_notifier")
.forJob(jobDetail).usingJobData(jobDataMap)
.withSchedule(SimpleScheduleBuilder.repeatMinutelyForever(10))
.startAt(new Date()).build();

Scheduler scheduler = SpringContext.getBean("schedulerFactoryBean");
scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear whether you start your Quartz scheduler **before** you execute the code above? If not, then it would explain why your trigger is not executed immediately even though you have startAt=new Date().

I would also recommend making sure the misfire instruction of the created trigger is set to  FIRE_NOW as that would make the scheduler execute the trigger in case a misfire happens (e.g. because the initial 'new Date()' time is missed). If that does not help, you may want to use startAt=(new Date() + few seconds) to deffer the first execution a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced with this issue too and found a small workaround for this. This is a cold-start problem. 
The way to achive this is to get scheduled fire time first:

```
Date scheduledCurrentJobTime = jobExecutionContext.getScheduledFireTime();
```

Then, when we have scheduled fire time, we can make a simple workaround for not implemented method to get previous fire-time:

```
public class CustomCronExpression extends CronExpression {  
    private static final String DELIMITER = " ";  
 /** 
  * Constructs a new <CODE>CronExpression</CODE> based on the specified 
  * parameter. 
  * 
  * @param cronExpression String representation of the cron expression the 
  *       new object should represent 
  * @throws java.text.ParseException if the string expression cannot be parsed into a valid 
  *         <CODE>CronExpression</CODE> 
  */  

  public CustomCronExpression(String cronExpression) throws ParseException {  
   super(cronExpression);  
  }  

  // here we can override this method and call it in future for the first-time   
  // launch to get previous time  
    @Override  
    public Date getTimeBefore(Date targetDate) {  
        Date nextFireTime = getTimeAfter(targetDate);  

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(getTimeZone());  
    calendar.setTime(nextFireTime);  
    calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, -1);  

    int dateUnit = getDateUnitCronExpression();  

  switch (dateUnit) {  
      case -1:  
          break;  
      case MINUTE:  
          calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, -1);  
          break;  
      case HOUR:  
       calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, -1);  
       break;  
      case DAY_OF_MONTH:  
      case DAY_OF_WEEK:  
       calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -1);  
       break;  
      case MONTH:  
       calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);  
       break;  
      default:  
       calendar.add(Calendar.YEAR, -1);  
       break;  
    }  

    Date previousDate = getTimeAfter(calendar.getTime());  
    Date afterPreviousDate = getTimeAfter(previousDate);  

    return findPreviousJobFireDate(afterPreviousDate, targetDate);  
  }  

  private int getDateUnitCronExpression() {  
    String cronExpression = getCronExpression();  
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(cronExpression)) {  
      return -1;  
    }  

    String[] expression = cronExpression.split(DELIMITER);

    return findDateUnitToWorkWith(expression);  
  }  

  private Date findPreviousJobFireDate(Date afterFuturePreviousDate, Date targetDate) {  
    Date futureDate = afterFuturePreviousDate;  
    Date resultDate = targetDate;  

    while (true) {  
      if (futureDate.equals(targetDate)) {  
       return resultDate;  
      } else {  
       resultDate = futureDate;  
       futureDate = getTimeAfter(resultDate);

       // prevent NPE and return current job time  
       if(futureDate == null) {  
         return resultDate;  
       }  
      }  
    }  
  }  

  private int findDateUnitToWorkWith(String[] expression) {  
   // * - represents the unit of date in the cron expression  
    // [0]Sec [1]Min [2]Hour [3]DayOfMonth [4]Month [5]DayOfWeek [6]Year  
    for (int i = 0, n = expression.length; i < n; i++) {  
      if (expression[i].equals("*")) {  
       return i;  
      }  
    }  
    return YEAR;  
  }   
}
```

`findDateUnitToWorkWith(String[] expression)` - this method will find first time * in cron expression. When we find it - first we should get next fire time and then substract one unit of date from next fire time.

I've described this with more details on my blog: [Quartz-scheduler cold-start problem](http://coffeedebug.blogspot.com/2013/10/qurtz-gettimebefore.html)